# How to find suitable PhD programs in Computational Social Science?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, social-media

I recently graduated from a master's program in Information Science in the U.S. and want to get into a Ph.D. program in the near future. I am pretty interested in computational social science, specifically, I love doing research about social media and understand online communities and social behaviors.

I'm wondering how to find some suitable Computational Social Science programs I can possible get into. I looked up some network science and social dynamics labs. They are pretty cool. But my concern is a lot of hubs of CSS are in CS/EE departments and the competitions are way much bigger than i-schools (where I finished my degree), and I do not very interested in getting too technical or engineering. A good blend of social focus and DS would be ideal for me.

Any suggestions on how I can make the best of the school searching in this specific filed and how to find some inner information are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite many and as you've studied Info Sci, I'd expect your professors to have pretty helpful informations on this. In Info Sci in particular UMich and Cornell have top tier PhD programs (School of Info at Michigan and Info Sci at Cornell), and they've some of the best in the world in computational social science. I should say, both of these are extremely competitive as you can imagine (and not any less competitive than CS programs I guess). There are also a number of other departments at umich and cornell that share faculty with those departments, e.g. complex systems, sociology, CS.

Comment: There are many other places too, I'll name a few: Indiana info sci, USC's and UW's info sci and also communication departments, UPenn communication, Northeastern network sci and political sci, Northwestern's Kellogg probably (I don't know about PhD programs, but they have many top researchers working in this area), Vermont complex systems institute (again, I don't know if they have a PhD program). I'd suggest also taking a look at the Santa Fe Institute and seeing where their external profs work. I strongly advise against going for a PhD because of one or two profs though, so be careful.

Comment: Some more disciplinary programs that do comp soc sci stuff as well: NYU data sci (very competitive and not focused on this, but still worth looking into), Duke, Penn State, and UNCCH sociology deps, UCLA communication, Carnegie Mellon social & decision sci and also their business school, MIT Sloan, and check out other business schools too, e.g. Fuqua & Wharton.
You should be careful if you decide to go with any of these though: 1. You should have a good reason to convince the admission committee that you're a good fit, and 2. You should make sure you actually want to be, e.g., a sociologist!

Comment: If you consider options outside of the US, there are plenty of places in Europe and a few in Canada as well (and I guess in other places too , but I don't know many except a few people in Korea). These are a few I remember right now:
UToronto and UBC sociology, CEU in Budapest/Vienna, Konstanz, Bremen, MPI for human development in Berlin, Leibniz institutes for social science in Mannheim and Cologne, QMU in London, Oxford's OII, Manchester sociology, Amsterdam (they're one of the best), Vienna complexity hub, and a few places in Paris (e.g. the french media lab in Sciences Po).

Comment: I can't emphasize enough though that if you're not from Europe and have not studied there, make sure you fully familiarize yourself with the education system before committing to a PhD in Europe (ideally through a few month of a research internship or something like that). e.g. in most places in Europe PhD is extremely advisor-centric, you're unlikely to receive much training and your PhD is equivalent to just the phase of the American PhD when you write your thesis (candidacy), and many other differences you should thoroughly research before deciding to go there!

Comment: + I forgot another good option in Europe: Alto in Finland (and also University of Helsinki I guess).

Answer (score 3):

There are several/many programs in Communication (which may sometimes refer to itself as Mass Communication and some related terms) that would be good places to study social media, online behavior, etc. using computational methods. Just going off the top of my head, I'd look at the PhD programs at University of North Carolina, University of California at Santa Barbara, Ohio State, University of Wisconsin at Madison, Northeastern University. I also know that Northeastern has an interdisciplinary network science program.

Basically every Communication program that I know of is actively trying to enhance their capacities in this area and would probably be attracted to prospective students with such interests as well. You should also know that competition for faculty jobs in this field is also much less fierce than in most other fields that I know about (there are typically more open positions than new PhDs in a given year). Of course, COVID-19 will cause a hopefully temporary downturn in available jobs in all fields.